# AWS boto3 grantfullcontrol syntax

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am using Python boto3 to grant full control to all objects in a bucket to another account.  Here is the snippet I have:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3') 
bucket = s3.Bucket("bucketname")
for key in bucket.objects.all():
    key.put(GrantFullControl="id=XXXX")
```

This code runs through fine and changes the owner however it rewrites the object with 0 bytes. Is this because the put method creates a new object? What is the method to change the ACL property?

Comment: Got it resolved. Put method creates the object and that is why rewrites an empty object with the same name. There is another method objectacl which updates the objects ACL properties. Below is my updated code:

for key in bucket.objects.all():
    s3.ObjectAcl("bucketname", key.key).put(GrantFullControl="id=XXX")

Answer (score 5):

Got it resolved. Put method apparently creates the object and that is why rewrites an empty object with the same name. There is another method objectacl which updates the objects ACL properties. Below is my updated code:

```
for key in bucket.objects.all(): s3.ObjectAcl("bucketname", 
    key.key).put(GrantFullControl="id=XXX")
```

Comment: Note here that XXX is the canonical user id.